# How can I improve my rendering performance in Java?

Tags: java, rendering, optimization

How can I improve the performance of my rendering? Currently, I'm rendering with java.awt.Graphics, but it seems to be starting to slow down since I'm adding new stuff to render.

My rendering setup:

Loading a spritesheet:
`Spritesheet sheet = new Spritesheet(ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/spritesheet.png"));`

Loading sprites:
`BufferedImage player = sheet.crop(5, 0, Spritesheet.DEF_WIDTH, Spritesheet.DEF_HEIGHT);`

And then rendering it with java.awt.Graphics in my gameloop:
`g.drawImage(player, x, y, Entity.DEF_WIDTH, Entity.DEF_HEIGHT);`

`Spritesheet.DEF_WIDTH` and `Spritesheet.DEF_HEIGHT` refer to 32px for quick access since most of my sprites are 32x32px. `Entity.DEF_WIDTH` and `Entity.DEF_HEIGHT` refer to 64px to render the entity on the screen.

One way I know that could solve my problem is that I could use smaller sprites but scale them up while rendering, but let's see if it's possible without that first.

Comment: Maybe this page is helpful? http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/

Comment: Completely understand. I think I'm going to make my sprites smaller and scale them when drawing them to the screen. And, when doing a new project, I'll keep in mind to try out a third-party API.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You sure you're using java.awt.graphics correctly? Im not sure if scaling helps in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, instead of relying on the ideas of people, who didn't see a single line of code or even a picture of your game, try profiling it, finding the bottleneck and removing it.

If that isn't option, here are some general tips:

- Scaling won't help if your sprites are only 32x32, period. Maybe it would use less RAM, but that's not a problem.
- Only render things if they are on the screen. If you render 900 bullets, but 99% of them aren't seen by the player, then you might as well just calculate the exact square root of 2, it would waste the same amount of processing power.
- Make sure you aren't loading the sprites every frame. IO is usually a blocking call, which means nothing else will happen on that thread until it finishes.
- Use more threads if you can. Make sure to tread carefully when doing that though, it can make your life much harder, than not using it.
- Try using an engine or a framework (not an APi if you actually want to finish the game). The CPU is not designed to render stuff, but the GPU is. Use it